# Add to CSS integer every x seconds using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a "fake" loading icon. I want to give the impression of loading for some calculations but in reality it is quick enough that it doesn't take long to load...

Instead I want to set it to increment my animation along every second until it is "complete". I am using CSS3 animations for the animation and am currently using css `hover` for the action. You can see it here if you hover on the icon: http://jsfiddle.net/77gkzqo2/

What I would like to do is be able to increment the relevant CSS every second.

Currently the "beer" has starting CSS as this (the glass is unfilled):

```
border-top:2px solid #F9F1DC; 
height:20%;
```

By the end of the animation it has reached:

```
border-top:14px solid #F9F1DC;
height:68%;
```

How can I use jQuery or just JavaScript to increment this?

The difference for the border is 12. The difference for the height percentage is 48.

Perhaps every 1 second, the border size increases by 4px and the height percentage increases by 16%. That means it would take 3 seconds to reach the ending size.

I am really struggling with the JavaScript as I have no idea whats best to use. I've written up some pseudo code I guess but no idea if I'm on the right track or how to flesh it out.

```
function addCSS(){
   // Somehow increment each value
   var height = [The CSS for the height]
   var border = [The CSS for the border]
   var newHeight = height + 16;
   var newBorder = border + 4;

   [set var newHeight as .filler's height]
   [set var newBorder as .fillers border size]
}

setInterval('addCSS();', 1000);
```

Comment: 1. Your fiddle seems to work fine without any JS at all, why do you need it? 2. Why do you need to slow down a load time just so you can show a pretty loading bar? Seems like bad UX to me.

Comment: @BrianS Did you read the question? It works on hover, not on time.

Comment: CSS animations/transitions are perfectly suited to handle static timed animations. Using JavaScript and even jQuery for that purpose is just blatant abuse.

Comment: Okay, that answers my first question (although I _think_ if you just add/remove a class for "full" vs. "empty" it should work, since you're using transitions), but not my second question.

Comment: @BrianS why is the second question of concern to you? Perhaps I have made a decision based on other factors. Perhaps I have had restrictions placed on me by a colleague or boss, perhaps I just want it that way.

Comment: @Johathan terribly sorry for somehow "abusing" JavaScript as you put it. Are we not allowed to use JavaScript when we want it or must it only be kept for special occasions?

Comment: I'm not trying to influence the decision making, but what precise problem is it that you feel requires JavaScript as a solution? You may be right, but I don't (yet) understand what it is that you're trying to solve...

Comment: @Francesca, Something like "my boss is making me do it" is a valid answer to "why are you doing this?" I asked because the description of the problem (a loading indicator for a process that is too fast to otherwise _see_ a loading indicator) seems to me like there is no problem present.

Comment: @DavidThomas I am trying to make the animation that currently occurs on hover (as in my JSFiddle) work based on increment of time instead. I also plan to have two versions of this (one that increments on time, one that increments on loading) hence wanting to find a non CSS version so that the latter can be completed using some of the shared code (rather than a CSS only version and then a separate jQuery/JavaScript version)

Comment: @BrianS this question was not about my decision to create this piece of code, it was looking for advice on how to do it. If you are not comfortable with the fact I am creating this, for whatever reason, simply don't read the question and move on to another for something you do agree with.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need jQuery to do that. Plus, I'm not sure you really wan't to do this on the :hover, but I think you just want to do it once when the page is loaded right?
If you want to animate it with JS every second, you don't think having the CSS in it's final states as a good option.

A simple way would be something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/77gkzqo2/2/) in native JS:

```
var filler = document.getElementById('filler');
var border = 2, height = 20;

var animate = setInterval(function() {
    if (border < 15) {
        border += 0.10;
        filler.style.borderTopWidth = border + 'px';
    }
    if (height < 68) {
        height += 0.40;
        filler.style.height = height + '%';
    }

    if (border>=15 && height>=68)
        clearInterval(animate);
}, 50);
```

You will definitely have better perf' than with using jQuery and I wouldn't recommend using jQuery if you are not comfortable with JS.

Of course it could be a lot improved but if you just want a simple fake loader this will do the work.

**Just a question: why do you want to make your website slow if it isn't?**

Comment: Seems to do the job, but it might be a bit hard to control/tweak the timing.

Comment: Yes, a good would to have an `iteration` variable and a `interval` one, then do some simple maths to get the the new values. It's pretty easy but I wanted to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

To get a css property, do this.

```
$('mySelector').css('border'); // returns "0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)"
```

Then to set

```
$('mySelector').css({'height' : 20, 'border' : 5})
```

So you could do this:

```
function addCSS(){
    var curBorder = $('mySelector').css('border').split('px')[0]; // We get only the numeric value.
    var curHeight = $('mySelector').css('height').split('px')[0];

    $('mySelector').css({'height' : curHeight + 16, 'border' : curBorder + 4});
}

setInterval(addCSS, 1000);
```

EDIT:
After playing around with this a bit: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7677a297/4/

Comment: @DavidThomas The op asked "How can I use jQuery to increment this?"

Comment: Ah, my apologies, yes: buried in the middle of the (apparently poorly-tagged) question. Down-vote retracted.

Comment: Apologies, I originally wrote this as a jQuery question but realised it may be possible without, so I removed my reference to jQuery and tagged it as JavaScript instead but I missed one. Either is fine. You can't win... if I didn't include jQuery everyone would moan it wasn't possible without it and if I say JavaScript then people blame me for being poorly tagged!

Comment: I've tested this out here by the way but cannot get it to run, perhaps it is my document ready? http://jsfiddle.net/7677a297/1/

Comment: Well you have a number of problems,
First of all because filler is a class the selector is '.filler' not just 'filler'.

secondly, because filler is a class you will get an array back so you need to call eq(0) to get the first result.

thirdly you do not have a 'border' defined in the css, so you need to change the 'border', to 'border-top'

Here are the fixes: 

http://jsfiddle.net/7677a297/1/

As you can see it goes of screen, you need to find the corrent limit and stop the call then.

Comment: People that moan about something being impossible without jQuery are advertising their inability to use, and work with, JavaScript as well as a fundamental lack of appreciation of what jQuery is. Tag your questions appropriately, and ignore those arguing that a task is possible only with their preferred technology. Your constraints are your constraints.

Comment: Hii, played around with it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/7677a297/4/
Seems to work like the original.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has some nice features to animate things in different ways. You could use the [animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), it allows you to specify what the new state should be and how long the transition should take.

If you're also using jQueryUI you might want to check [its toggleClass function](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleclass/) so you can use classes and keep styling in css.

It doesn't really make sense to include libraries specifically for this one purpose, but if you're using them anyway you could as well use the animation functions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS `animation` and skip JS altogether when animating an element: http://jsfiddle.net/r571d1fh/.  JS/jQuery could be used to activate the animation.

For fun, here's a version where the glass visual is built using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/w1c06x1p/.

HTML:

```
<div class="glass">
    <div class="beer">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/idIq4qb.png" />
        <div class="filler"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    background-color:#d1dfea;
    height:400px;
}

.glass {
    min-height:24em;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.beer {
    position:relative;
}

.filler {
    position:absolute;
    border-top:2px solid #F9F1DC; 
    z-index:-1;
    bottom:5px;
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:orange;
    -webkit-animation: fill-it-up 5s linear infinite;
    animation: fill-it-up 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fill-it-up {
    0% {
        border-top:2px solid #F9F1DC;   
        height: 20%;
    }

    100% {
        border-top:15px solid #F9F1DC;
        height: 68%;
    }
}

@keyframes fill-it-up {
    0% {
        border-top:2px solid #F9F1DC;   
        height: 20%;
    }

    100% {
        border-top:15px solid #F9F1DC;
        height: 68%;
    }
}
```